# Why does racism drop the 'e' but ageism retains it?

Tags: orthography, suffixes, clipping

Other examples include elitism, ableism, and wokeism, although the latter neologism seems to have a lively minor variant: wokism.  It is difficult for me to see any rational basis for including or excluding the 'e'.

In ableism, the 'le' is a suffix, where presumably the base word is ability, so that makes a little sense, but in elitism the base is elite and in ageism the base is age.  There is the distinction between monosyllabic and polysyllabic. For example absolutism, activism, collectivism, communism, and determinism at least partially confirm that thesis, but ableism, absenteeism, and fideism indicate it is not a hard distinction.  Additionally, there is cubism, nudism, truism, and mutism with monosyllabic bases, that nevertheless omit the 'e'.

Then too, there is baptism which truncates the base word baptize, but is different from ableism which truncates ability.  Likewise bowdlerism truncates bowdlerize and conservatism truncates conservative.  On the other hand there are activism, collectivism, descriptivism, positivism, negativism, nativism, passivism, primitivism, progressivism, relativism, subjectivism, objectivism, and constructivism which follow the polysyllabic pattern.

The spelling checker here tells me all of ableism, ablism, wokeism and wokism are misspellings, but google recognizes wokeism and ableism as correct.  Likewise, bowdlerism, fideism, mutism, descriptivism, nativism, passivism, primitivism, progressivism, subjectivism, objectivism, and constructivism are unrecognized here, but are recognized by google.

Comment: There seems to be a clear [origin of ageism](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=ageism) in 1969, but no explanation of why it was spelt that way. Others with an e like [ableism](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=ableism) seem to be later. I don't think there's a profound reason behind it (or a law/rule), just people copying other people, but there's maybe still a story to be told.

Comment: Compare _aging_ (US) vs _ageing_ (UK).

Comment: English spelling is no kinder to newly-coined words than it is to others. It doesn't represent English pronunciation, and new words are always spoken before they're written, not least because while it's easy to add _-ism_ to _age_ in speech, it's a toughie to spell. There are several solutions, none really great, but all were tried repeatedly, regardless. Nobody is in charge of spelling, see.

Comment: I think the ones that retain the "e" are because it may be difficult to recognize the original stem without it. "ablism" might be read as a-blism, and "agism" as a-gism (perhaps with a hard G). I doubt it's a coincidence that these are very short stems.

Answer (score 1):

It is common in English to add the letter “e” to soften the letter “g” so “ageism” is quite proper.

There is also a modern tendency to omit a “e” anywhere it’s seen as redundant.  One example is the modern preference for “judgment” (by judges themselves) instead of “judgement”.